# Understanding the hierarchy of Entity Framework modules

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Since I've started to use Entity Framework I've noticed that it has a lot of modules. In NuGet you can find

- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore,
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer,
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools

and so much more. How I understand it: EF have inside hundreds child modules, so you don't need to install the whole EF, only parts you will need. **The question is where can I see the whole structure of EF? Which modules are parents/children of some modules?**